# How to access number of controls as a name in c#?

Tags: c#, button, controls

Seems there is 10 buttons on a winform in c#. button1, button2, button3 and button10. When I click on button3 I need to get 3 as its number. Is it possible to do this?

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(button1.number); //Show 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ.

```
Button btn = (Button) sender;
int number = int.Parse(new string(btn.Name
    .Reverse()
    .TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit)
    .Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should name your buttons as  1, 2..etc

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var button = (Button)sender;
 MessageBox.Show(button.name);
}
```

Comment: Those are terrible names for buttons! That being said, it would work. I just wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add that number to the AccessibleName of each button, then when the code captures the click event (which should be the same for all buttons) just ask what the name is:

```
 Button btn = (Button) sender;
 switch (btn.AccessibleName) {
    case "1":
       //blah
  }
```

Comment: If its already the string "1" why not just use it? What is the purpose of the switch?

Comment: Yup, you could easily just parse the button name and strip off the "button" part and be left with the number.  More than one way to skin a cat.  The switch is obviously to permit various processing according to the button.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Assign the string "1" to the `Tag` property of your button, then write:

   ```
   MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Tag.ToString()); //Show 1
   ```
2. Assuming the naming convention remains constant, use substring to strip off the "button" part of the name:

   ```
   string name = (sender as Button).Name;
   MessageBox.Show(name.Substring(7)); //Show 1
   ```

MSDN for `Tag`: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)